# when trying to impute using linear regression Pandas producing truth value error specific to my case

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to impute a column based on 3 column value linear regression output.

here is the code

```
for i in range(len(data)):

    #check to see if the value is zero, yes then proceed with regression imputation'
    #debugging shows after for loop is executed with i=0 , then i is not defined.This is the error i do not understand.
    if data.iloc[i:-1] == '0':

        #create a dataframe using values for that row and use predict

        x = pd.DataFrame({'perception_score': [data.iloc[i, -6]],'Rating_new': [data.iloc[i, -3]/100], 'Experience': [data.iloc[i, -12]/66]})

        data.iloc[i:-1] = lm.predict(x)

    else:

        #if non zero replace the value with the values in the 3rd last column

data.iloc[i:-1] = [data.iloc[i, -3]/100]
```

But  I am getting an error like this.

```
  .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi user10573543, do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I went through the example the above code is complete `len(data)=500'. `data` is a data frame containing 11 columns all having a numerical value. I am checking in one column if a 0 is hit in one row take the corresponding values from different columns and impute using linear regression, the predict( it no the point of error) helps me in achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the mistake was in the code instead of `data.iloc[i:-1]` i just had to use `data.iloc[i:-1]` Then only columns are selected a silly mistake.